# How to display one slide at a time and remove the blank at the end? (react-slick)

Tags: reactjs, react-slick

How to display one slide at a time and remove the blank at the end?
I need to output 1 word at a time, but at the same time get rid of the void at the end

```
My problem img:
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmx5L.png)

How to do this, given that each element has a different width

```
Need to img
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMsKR.png)

*I'll leave the codepen in the comments with what happened*

Comment: https://codepen.io/devlucker/pen/WNGdBGv

Comment: it looks an unsolved issue from your given your setting. you can see some issues about it: https://github.com/akiran/react-slick/issues/1334 https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/877